# Can't watch a public field of type vector< vector<int> > of an instance of a custom object

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class travel
{
public:
       vector< vector<int> > trace;
};
```

In a class that includes the previous .cpp, I instantiate a travel object and then assign the following to the trace field

```
tempTravel.trace[iteration-1][1] = 1;
```

I want to watch `tempTravel.trace[5][1]` throughout execution while stepping through. However, nothing shows up in the watch field for the value and if I instead watch `tempTravel.trace` an gradually open up the plus sign to hone into the lower level members of the object, I don't see any values defined. If there any way I can watch ?

Comment: What kind of compile options do you have set? Are you using `-g` (for debugging) for any `-O<N>` options (for optimizations)?

Comment: Not sure, but I use the debugger of codeblocks to run the thing, but I can't access the vector elements in the watch window.